# Create @timestamp when date only occur once in file with Logstash

Tags: date, filter, logstash

I have been searching around for an answer to this problem that I have with Logstash without luck.

I have files where events are logged with a timestamp on the following format:
HH:mm:ss.SSS - an example could be '08:21:03.571'. I should also say that the day is logged at the beginning of the file i.e. not logged for every event.

So, to my problem:
In order to count the number of events that occur during a time period, I want to parse my timestamp and then put it into the @timestamp field. However, it seems that the @timestamp field requires more information than the timestamp (HH:mm:ss.SSS) gives. If I understand correctly, the @timestamp field also needs the day the event was logged. This leads to my question:

How can I 'save' the date in the beginning of the file? I would want to concat this date with the time of every event so that I can use @timestamp as target field with the date filter.

The logged date in the beginning of the file looks like this: 
Local Time:             2016-02-29T08:21:02.142

So, ideally my input would be something like: 
08:21:02.165

And I would want the output to look something like:

```
{
   "message" => "08:21:03.571"
   "@timestamp" => 2016-02-29T08:21:03.571Z
}
```

Thanks in advance

Jonas

Comment: Did you post this last week too? There is no clear way to save a variable from one message and use it in other messages in logstash, AFAIK. What you could do is use the ruby filter to execute a ruby script in which you could store the date to a file and then later message processing could use this file. I don't know how to ruby script that so this is a comment, not an answer. You may also think about creating a github issue @ logstash and get an answer from the devs.

Comment: @WillBarnwell Thanks for answering. I did not post this last week. In fact, this is the first time ever I ask a question on Stackoverflow, hence the new account. 
Okay, I will look further into this. Thanks again.